# R18n doesn't work in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, rubygems

For some reason I cannot use R18n although its loaded. Can some someone give me a hint?

```
o0sel:~/rails_projects/demo> rails --version 
o0sel:~/rails_projects/demo> rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.5)
>> I18n.tr<tab><tab>
I18n.translate      I18n.translate!     I18n.transliterate  I18n.trust          I18n.try            
>> R18n.tr<tab><tab>
R18n.trust  R18n.try    
>> exit
o0sel:~/rails_projects/demo> ruby 
o0sel:~/rails_projects/demo> bundle install 
Using rake (0.8.7)  
Using abstract (1.0.0)  
Using Activesupport (3.0.5)  
Using builder (2.1.2)  
Using i18n (0.5.0)  
Using activemodel (3.0.5)  
Using erubis (2.6.6)  
Using rack (1.2.2)  
Using rack-mount (0.6.13)  
Using rack-test (0.5.7)  
Using tzinfo (0.3.25)  
Using actionpack (3.0.5)  
Using mime-types (1.16)  
Using polyglot (0.3.1)  
Using treetop (1.4.9)  
Using mail (2.2.15) 
Using actionmailer (3.0.5)  
Using arel (2.0.9)  
Using activerecord (3.0.5) 
Using activeresource (3.0.5)  
Using bundler (1.0.10)  
Using haml (3.0.25) 
Using nifty-generators (0.4.5)  
Using r18n-core (0.4.9)  
Using r18n-rails-api (0.4.9)  
Using r18n-rails (0.4.9)  
Using thor (0.14.6)  
Using railties (3.0.5) 
Using rails (3.0.5)  
Using sqlite3 (1.3.3)
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had problems with r18n-desktop + actionmailer gems, but overcome it by creating separate gemset. It contained only action_mailer + dependencies, not whole rails stack.